# Ubuntu 16.04 display is elongated on startup

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I have accidentally pressed <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> key, which caused the display to be elongated. I have pressed the same key combination to return to normal state. But every time the system boots, the display is again elongated. So I need to press the same <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> every time. How do I avoid this? 
[image: After boot]
[image: Pressing super + L]
[image: Normal screen]

Comment: so just for clarification the elongation never happened before the accident?

Comment: @delfiler: No, it was never happened before

Comment: Did you check `unity-control-center` > `Displays`?

Comment: @Arun Just for Clarification.. 1. One day Accidentally you pressed Win+P and then system Elongated. 2. you again pressed Win+P and the screen became as regular. 3. you worked for several hours and then shutdown the system. 4. when you switch on the system, it is showing as Elongated. 5. then you are pressing Win+P to make it normal. Then steps 3 to 5 are repeated rite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78759/discussion-between-arun-and-pratap).

Comment: @kenn: I have checked this in `Displays`. If there is a command to set default display to 1366x768, it will solve the problem

Comment: I am not an expert but since it's a user specific issue, you can try `mv  ~/.Xauthority  ~/.Xauthority.bak` and `mv ~/.ICEauthority  ~/.ICEauthority.bak` then log out and log in. You can also check out the content of `~/.dmrc` but do not move it, ` cat ~/.dmrc`

Comment: I also found this `~/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: I believe this one will fix your problem http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: Thank you @kenn. The first two solutions did not work. I've found monitors.xml is a dynamic file and it changes according to resolution.

Comment: @kenn Nice Solution. I have checked as per above .xml file. Its working.

Comment: You can find more comprehensive info in this link : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: 1. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` to reinstall a graphic environment.
If problem still exists:
2. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg` to reinstall `xserver`.
If problem still exists:
3. `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.bak`, then `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Comment: **@kenn** if what you commented worked, can you convert that to an answer?  otherwise **Arun** do you still have the problem or did kenn's comment help?

Comment: @Fabby Tried kenn's solution, unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: **Arun** do you have the same problem under the guest account?

Comment: **@Fabby** : I have logged in as a guest when booting up. There was no issue with any other accounts.